# Golang: Passar Struct aninhada para HTMLtemplate

Tags: struct, golang

Boa Tarde a todos!

Estou precisando de uma ajuda, tenho duas structs que estão no pacote controller conforme abaixo:

```
type ListValidation struct{
   Id int
   Nameplan string
   Escop string
   Data string
}

type ListTests struct{
   Id int
   TestName string
   TestsSteps string
   DataNow string
}
```

Os valores dessas duas structs são preenchidos e em seguida é repassado para outra struct que esta no pacote "routes":

```
validation, tests := controller.ExecutValidationPage(id)

type DadosRecebidos struct{
   DadosStructValidation controller.ListValidation
   DadosStructTests controller.ListTests
}

dadosStruct := DadosRecebidos{}

dadosStruct.DadosStructValidation = validation
dadosStruct.DadosStructTests = tests

tmplt.ExecuteTemplate(w, "execvalidation", dadosStruct)
```

Conforme o código acima estou passando os dados para o meu template html, porem não sei como posso exibir os dados nas tags do html, quando uso uma struct não aninhada só preciso declarar {{. Nameplan}} entre as tags que o valor é repassado, mas com esse tipo de struct aninhada não sei como. Conseguiriam me dar um help?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas maneiras que resolve isso...

Por 'encoding/json' e 'interface{}'

```
type ListValidation struct {
    Id       int
    Nameplan string
    Escop    string
    Data     string
}

lv := ListValidation{
    Id:       10,
    Nameplan: "NamePlan sample",
    Escop:    "Escop sample",
    Data:     "Data sample",
}

type ListTests struct {
    Id         int
    TestName   string
    TestsSteps string
    DataNow    string
}

lt := ListTests{
    Id:         20,
    TestName:   "TestName sample",
    TestsSteps: "TestsStepes sample",
    DataNow:    "DataNow sample",
}

type DadosRecebidos struct {
    DadosStructValidation ListValidation
    DadosStructTests      ListTests
}

dr := DadosRecebidos{
    lv,
    lt,
}

var data interface{}
dataBytes, _ := json.Marshal(dr)
json.Unmarshal(dataBytes, &data)

tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./views/test.html"))
tmpl.Execute(w, data)
```

Ou pela *library* ["github.com/fatih/structs"](https://github.com/fatih/structs)

```
type ListValidation struct {
    Id       int
    Nameplan string
    Escop    string
    Data     string
}

lv := ListValidation{
    Id:       10,
    Nameplan: "NamePlan sample",
    Escop:    "Escop sample",
    Data:     "Data sample",
}

type ListTests struct {
    Id         int
    TestName   string
    TestsSteps string
    DataNow    string
}

lt := ListTests{
    Id:         20,
    TestName:   "TestName sample",
    TestsSteps: "TestsStepes sample",
    DataNow:    "DataNow sample",
}

type DadosRecebidos struct {
    DadosStructValidation ListValidation
    DadosStructTests      ListTests
}

dr := DadosRecebidos{
    lv,
    lt,
}

mp := structs.Map(dr)

tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./views/test.html"))
tmpl.Execute(w, mp)
```

No Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Request Test</h1>
    {{.DadosStructValidation.Nameplan}}<br>
    {{.DadosStructTests.TestName}}

</body>
</html>
```